# Send parameter by url in login laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Take the routes out of the auth and put them in **web.php**, I want to send a parameter through the url for the login but it throws me an error.

```
Route::get('login/{url}', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Route [login/{url}] not defined. (View: C:\wamp64\www\portalmecanico_copia\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Route [login/{url}] not defined. (0)

Comment: Por favor, debe preguntar en idioma inglesa. Sino, puede intentar https://es.stackoverflow.com/ por preguntas en espanol.

Comment: are you calling `route('login/{url}')` somewhere?

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login/{url}') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Login') }}">
                        
                    </form>` @lagbox

Comment: does it work that way? I use `route('myroutename')` everywhere instead of passing the actual url of the route. So in your case that would be `route('login')` (your second route has no name btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `route` helper you are referencing the route name for the route. In this case the `POST` route doesn't have a name, so you should name it:

```
Route::post('login', ...)->name('post-login');

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('post-login') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Login') }}">
```

Your `POST` route isn't defining any route parameter so not sure what you want done with the `url` parameter from the `GET` route.

If you want to have the `GET` and `POST` route for `login` to take the same parameter you can do that without naming the POST route:

```
Route::get('login/{url}', ...)->name('login');
Route::post('login/{url}', ...);

 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login', ['url' => ...]) }}" aria-label="{{ __('Login') }}">
```

Comment: Sorry it's not for post, I'm showing the login view but I want to add the url parameter to that view. But I get that error.

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: login/{url}]. (View: C:\wamp64\www\portalmecanico_copia\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)

Comment: and how is it concatenated there @lagbox

Comment: @user947840 how is what concatenated where?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to resolve you error. you have to do this in your form action

```
<form method="get" action="{{ route('login', ['url' => 'specify the parameter here']) }}" aria-label="{{ __('Login') }}">
```

the {url} is just like variable.

but if you want to set your form method to post, you have to specified the route name, or you just can do with `http://localhost/login`

Comment: and how is it concatenated there @ilubis